# Нужна ли синхронизация?

Tags: delphi, vba, макросы, ole

Вопрос может оказаться очень глупым, но мне всё же интересно. Есть такой код:

```
EXL:=CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
...
EXL.Run('makrosv_vba');
...
```

Теперь то, что мне хотелось бы уяснить. Оператор EXL.Run('makrosv_vba') полностью выполняет макрос или просто кидает в екселевский vba команду на выполнение и будь здоров? Другими словами, нужна ли синхронизация (макрос довольно тяжёлый, и мне нужно, чтобы дальнейший код Delphi выполнялся только после макроса)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Синхронно, будет ждать.

Comment: Да, немного протестировал с задержкой выполнения кода vba, действительно ждёт